# After git checkout node_modules are saved in other branch

Tags: git, git-branch, gitignore, git-checkout

I have added new folder where are node_modules and they are ignored, like this:

```
folder
 -node_modules
folder1
 -node_modules
 -app
```

folder1 and folder are in second branch, and in master branch is just folder.

After I switch from second branch to master node modules are saved and I get like this in master:

```
folder
 -node_modules
folder1
 -node_modules
```

How to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: `and they are ignored` ... what does this mean?

Comment: .gitingore ....

Comment: My guess is that in `master` these files/folders are already versioned in Git.  In this case, having added them to `gitignore` after the fact won't make them be ignored.

Comment: Ok, what is solution to ignore node_modules after I switch branch?

Comment: Same problem here - how was this resolved?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914838/git-moves-files-folders-with-when-checking-other-branches-although-i-use-stash-b

Comment: Untracked files are **not on a branch**. If you switch branches, Git will leave all untracked files alone. This includes `.gitignore`d files too. Does that answer your question? I have to find a canonical q/a first to mark it as dupe